# How do I extract a value from this Ruby hash?

Tags: ruby, json, api, parsing, hash

I'm using the Foursquare API, and I want to extract the "id" value from this hash

```
[{"id"=>"4fe89779e4b09fd3748d3c5a", "name"=>"Hitcrowd", "contact"=>{"phone"=>"8662012805", "formattedPhone"=>"(866) 201-2805", "twitter"=>"hitcrowd"}, "location"=>{"address"=>"1275 Glenlivet Drive", "crossStreet"=>"Route 100", "lat"=>40.59089895083072, "lng"=>-75.6291255071468, "postalCode"=>"18106", "city"=>"Allentown", "state"=>"Pa", "country"=>"United States", "cc"=>"US"}, "categories"=>[{"id"=>"4bf58dd8d48988d125941735", "name"=>"Tech Startup", "pluralName"=>"Tech Startups", "shortName"=>"Tech Startup", "icon"=>"https://foursquare.com/img/categories/shops/technology.png", "parents"=>["Professional & Other Places", "Offices"], "primary"=>true}], "verified"=>true, "stats"=>{"checkinsCount"=>86, "usersCount"=>4, "tipCount"=>0}, "url"=>"http://www.hitcrowd.com", "likes"=>{"count"=>0, "groups"=>[]}, "beenHere"=>{"count"=>0}, "storeId"=>""}]
```

When I try to extract it by using `['id']`, I get this error `can't convert Symbol into Integer`. How do I extract the value using ruby? Also, how do I do this for multiple hashes extracting the "id" value each time?

Please pardon my inexperience. Thanks!

Comment: It looks like this is an array with one value, a hash. does `yourobject.first['id']` work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's wrapped in an array, that's what the `[` and `]` mean on the start and end.  But it also looks like this array only one object in it, which is the hash you really want.

So assuming you want the first object in this array:

```
mydata[0]['id'] # or mydata.first['id'] as Factor Mystic suggests
```

But usually when an API returns an Array there is a reason (it might return many results instead of just one), and naively plucking the first item from it my not be what you want.  So be sure you are getting the kind of data you really expect before hard coding this into your application.

Comment: This works, but what if I want to run this code for multiple arrays?

Comment: Multiple arrays? Or multiple items in one array?  Either way, loops are cool, I guess. That's sort of a vague question.

Comment: Sorry, I meant multiple items in one array. Sorry about the ambiguity.

Answer (score 2):

For multiple hashes, if you want to *do something with* the id (run a procedure of some kind) then

```
resultsArray.each do |person|
  id = person["id"] #then do something with the id
end
```

If you want to just *get an array containing the ids* then

```
resultsArray.map{|person| person["id"]}  
# ["4fe89779e4b09fd3748d3c5a", "5df890079e4b09fd3748d3c5a"]
```

To just grab the one item from the array, see [Alex Wayne](https://stackoverflow.com/users/62076/alex-wayne)'s answer

Comment: I get this error for the second piece of code `undefined method 'id' for #<Hash:0x1681ab8>`

Answer (score 0):

To get an array of ids, try: `resultsArray.map { |result| result["id"] }`